# J 3.4 | Beez 3 | Customizing

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I have copied the default Beez3 template to another name in order to customize the design and layout without disturbing the original template. Most modifications are taking place in the copy's *personal.css* file.

I have also changed the constant names in the file */templates/mytemplatename/language/en-GB/en-GB-tpl_tps.ini* from TPL_BEEZ3_* to TPL_TPS_* to remove references to the Beez3 template.

Since changing those constant names, the site now displays those constant names instead of the values defined in the .ini file.  The text links for changing the font size also displays 'undefined'.

Exactly how do I fix this ??
Any tips greatly appreciated !

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The language files located under your /templates/mytemplatename/language/en-GB/ folder are intended for installation process purpose. Since you're manually duplicating the template files, you need to copy the language files manually to this folder too : /language/en-GB/en-GB.tpl_tps.ini

Comment: Thank you very much webchun !
Looking in the folder you indicated, I saw the files were already there...  I guess the template copy process put them there.  I changed the prefixes in those .ini and .sys files and... Viola !!